# Safe to Smarty {include} without file attribute?

Tags: smarty, smarty3

For example, `{include 'path/to/template.tpl'}`?

<strike>There's no mention in the documentation of said format, but</strike> it seems to work identically to:

```
{include file='path/to/template.tpl'}
```

Is this a quirk, or by design? I prefer the tidier syntax for when I'm not passing additional vars, but want to be sure it's an accepted format (ver. 3.0.7).

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood you correct but both methods are correct / accepted. At the documentation, you can see the shorthand method in action too http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.include.tpl (section 7.53.)

Comment: @sofl Welp. That shows how attentive I am to documentation :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{include "foo"}`, `{extend "foo"}` etc. are shorthand notations (deliberately) introduced in Smarty3. It is safe to use them. There are a bunch of these, e.g. `{foreach $foo as $bar}` (compared to `{foreach from=$foo item="bar"}`). They don't differ performance-wise, so it really just boils down to your personal / team preference.